# Are women allowed to blow conch shell (Shankha) in Hinduism?

Tags: women, puja, lakshmi, skanda-purana, brahma-vaivarta-purana

I've heard that it is mentioned that Lakshmi doesn't reside in homes/leaves that home were women or shudra blows conch, it is mentioned in Brahm-vaivarta puran, prakriti khand, adhyaya 20, shloka 21 or 31, something.

Is it really true?

Answer (score 0):

There's a niṣedha on the blowing of śaṅkha by strī in Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa & Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa. The relevant ślokas are as follows -

> strīṇāṁ ca śaṅkhadhvanibhiḥ śūdrāṇāṁ ca viśeṣataḥ // 
> bhītā ruṣṭā yāti lakṣmīstatsthalādanyadeśataḥ / 
> ~ Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa ([1.23.27b-28a](https://archive.org/details/QWtF_devi-bhagvata-vol-2-khemraj/page/n495/mode/2up?view=theater))

> strīṇāṁ ca śaṅkhadhvanibhiḥ śūdrāṇām ca viśeṣataḥ / 
> bhītā ruṣṭā yāti lakṣmīḥ sthalamanyatsthalāttatāḥ // 
> ~ Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa ([2.20.30](https://archive.org/details/BrahmavaivartaMahapuranam_sanskrit/BrahmavaivartaMahapuranam-Part1/page/n173/mode/2up?view=theater))

Both the ślokas are same, with a slight difference in the last term, that doesn't change the meaning. The gist of the śloka is - upon the blowing of śaṅkha by strī and śūdra, Devī Lakṣmī gets bhīta and ruṣṭa, and leaves that sthāna, going elsewhere. 
I am not able to find any Sanskrit comm. on Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa. 
In [his comm. on Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa(1.23.27b)](https://archive.org/details/SrimadDeviBhagavatamWithTheTikaOfNilankantha/page/n773/mode/2up?view=theater), Nīlakaṇṭha says -

> strīnāṁ ceti // strīśūdraiḥ śaṅkhadhvanirnakartavya ityarthaḥ //

Here, Nīlakaṇṭha states nothing more than just that strī and śūdra should not blow śaṅkha, as per the śloka. Due to being unable to find further commentaries and mentions of this niṣedha, I am unable to list any śāstrīya specifications regarding the niṣedha. For e.g. specifications like blowing śaṅkha is niṣiddha for gṛhiṇīs and/or strīs during their menses, but not for saṁnyāsinīs.
But there is no need to doubt the prāmāṇya of the śāstrīya niṣedha.

Comment: In Bengal, this prohibition is meant to be observed while worshipping Lakshmi as the primary deity only, for She is described to be fond of silence. Raghunandana states that no instrument, even the bell, shouldn't be rung while worshipping Lakshmi, but this practice isn't seen elsewhere.

Comment: @অনু May I know who is Raghunandana? And are you referring to a śāstra or just the followed practice? In Bengal anyway, a lot of things are done, which are clearly niṣiddha, as per śāstras. For e.g. Brāhmaṇas doing matsyabhakṣaṇa, which is clearly pāpakarman on their part, unless that is prasāda of some śāstra-vihita bali (such as in a śrauta somayajña). Thanks

Comment: @Raghunandana Bhattacharya was a celebrated 15th century Bengali smrti-nibandhakara. To know about nidbandhas & nibandhakaras, read History of Dharmashastra Vol 1 (both parts) by Bharataratna Mahamahopadhyaya P. V. Kane.

Comment: Thanks, I do know about dharmanibandhas as well as PV Kane's History of Dharmaśāstra, but have never read Raghunandana's work. Is his work written in Bengali or in Saṁskṛta? If it's in Bengali, I wouldn't be able to read it unfortunately. And could you please tell the relevant ślokas from his work, which talk about this? It would be great if you could share that here, or in an answer to this post.

Comment: Regarding fish consumption, not only Bengali brahmins, but Axomiya, Maithili & Odiya brahmins also consume fish as a part of their daily diet. There are several such local customs practiced by various Hindu communities that can deemed as nisiddha. For example-varnashankara castes (like kayasthas & abhiras) claiming Kshatriya & Vaishya status without undergoing upanayana in North India, marrying one's own maternal cousin in South India, intermarriage with a Sikh belonging to the same caste in greater Punjab region, veneration of Guru Nanak among Punjabi & Sindhi Hindus & so on.

Comment: Raghunandana's magnum opus Smrtitattva is written In Sanskrit & has been printed in both Eastern Nagari (Bengali - Assamese) & Devanagari scripts. Here are the links to Devanagari versions. https://archive.org/details/smrititattvaraghunandabhattacharyavolume1jivanandavidyasagara1895lq_202003_873_Z https://archive.org/details/riSt_smriti-tattva-vol-2-of-shri-raghunandan-bhattacharya-by-shri-jivananda-vidyasaga

Comment: I do agree that there are certain practices, which can be accepted under deśadharmas, being valid for a particular deśa, but being niṣiddha in others. But not all practices qualify as such. As for vivāha of a man with maternal cousin in Southern India, that's talked about and accepted by many smṛtikāras such as Mādhavācārya, Devaṇa Bhaṭṭa, etc. under deśadharma.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the smṛti. @অনু Does Smṛtitattva contain the info related to śaṅkhadhvani being varjita for Lakṣmī, that you shared? And if so, where?

Comment: Regarding your original query, custom/deshachara has a complementary authority with shastras in real life scenarios, so it can't be ignored. Smritis too recognize the authority of deshachara.

Comment: I don't disagree on the matter of deśadharmas. Deśadharmas have been talked about not only by nibandhakāras but also mentioned in dharmasūtras such as Baudhāyana. And there are surely varying positions on such matters, by even ācāryas such as Baudhāyana, Gautama, etc. However, it's important to note that not *all* niṣiddha ācāras, which are prominent in a deśa, become valid, as per śāstra. Even nibandhakāras don't take such a wild position. @অনু

Comment: Raghunandana doesn't mentions about shankhadhvani, but he do mentions about ringing the bell as a substitute for all vadyas in Ahnikatattva & expressedly forbids ringing of the bell while worshipping Lakshmi in Krtyatattva (or Tithitattva), so it's easy to assume that if application of substitutes of vadyas are forbidden, then original vadyas too must be forbidden.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151549/discussion-between--and-bingming).